# LaTeX beginner, pgfplots graph not appearing on overleaf

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

Here is the code I wrote, trying to get a graph of `3x+2y=900`

```
\documentclass{standalone}       
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}    
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=100,ymin=0, ymax=1000, axisline=center, axisontop=true, domain=0,100] 
   \addplot{mark=none,draw=red, ultra thick} {$3x+2y=900$};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. // I‘m missing the documentclass and the document environment …

Answer (score 5):

Some syntaxes are wrong. It should be `axis lines=center`, `axis on top=true`, `domain=0:100`. And if you plot 2 dimensional curve, the function you put in should be the expression for `y` without inside the $ signs, such as `(900-3*x)/2`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=100,ymin=0, ymax=1000, axis lines=center, axis on top=true, domain=0:100]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red, ultra thick] {(900-3*x)/2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]